# How to display an asset (pdf) from both site languages on both sites?

Tags: entry, language

How do I display an asset (PDF) from both site languages on both sites? I would like to offer both German and English versions of a PDF on both the English and German sites.

I now have `{{ entry.PDF.url }}` and wondered if I can add a `.site()` direction to the entry query.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and fetch the other pdf by creating an entry query for the different language, and getting the pdf from there.

```php
{# if you have only 2 languages: #}
{% set otherLanguage = craft.entries().id(entry.id).siteId(['not', entry.siteId).one() %}
{{ otherLanguage.PDF.url }}


{# if you have more languages (and want all the PDFs: #}
{% set otherLanguages = craft.entries().id(entry.id).siteId(['not', entry.siteId).all() %}
{% for $otherLanguage in $otherLanguages %}
    {{ otherLanguage.PDF.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: THanks, that works!!